# I would like to know how to make these container

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-design

I would like to know how to make these containers.

Container Code of Now

```
  Container(
                    width: screenWidth / 1.1,
                    height: screenHeight / 6,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.1),
                        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
)
```

[image]

back greeen color

```
#0E8375
```

Answer (score 1):

Add [glassmorphism](https://pub.dev/packages/glassmorphism) Package in pubspec.yaml File and try this.

```
GlassmorphicContainer(
                            width: 400,
                            height: 200,
                            borderRadius: 20,
                            blur: 10,
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            linearGradient: LinearGradient(
                              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                              colors: [
                                const Color(0xFFffffff).withOpacity(0.3),
                                const Color(0xFFFFFFFF).withOpacity(0.10),
                              ],
                              stops: const [
                                0.1,
                                1,
                              ],
                            ),
                            borderGradient: LinearGradient(
                              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                              colors: [
                                const Color(0xFFffffff).withOpacity(0.3),
                                const Color((0xFFFFFFFF)).withOpacity(0.05),
                              ],
                            ),
                            border: 0,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                             
                            ),
                          ),
```